# Реализовать полоски и круги с цветными сегментами, как дано в 3D макете дизайнера?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, snapsvg

Подскажите как реализовать?
 На 1 скрине фотошоп показывает, что это картинка или делать текстом лучше?
На 2 скрине, как лучше сделать полоску с картинкой, полоску с кружком отдельно?
Через div сделать или слить вместе с картинкой лучше?
**скрин-1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**скрин-2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Нет не картиками.
2. Да, вам тут все надо делать с помощью html+css. И может быть даже JS, кое-где.

Answer (score 2):

Разную длину цветной полоски вокруг окружности можно реализовать с помощью: [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) и [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)

Регулирование длины полоски осуществляется изменением параметров этих атрибутов.

Например:

**stroke-dashoffset** - (отступ от начала линии), при изменении  параметра от максимума до нуля, можно увеличивать видимую часть линии от 0 до полной длины.

**stroke-dasharray** - чередование черточек (1 параметр) и пробелов (2-ой параметр)

Изменяя первый параметр можно изменять длину черты, при этом нужно уменьшать 2-ой параметр - пробел.

В примере ниже -   `stroke-dasharray="83.7 167.5`, где `83.7` длина черты, `167.5` - пробел

Сумма этих двух величин должна быть равна длине целой окружности `2 * 3.14 * 40 = 251.2`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<!--Серая окружность -->
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="1" />

<!-- Цветной сегмент -->
<path id="progress" stroke-width="3" stroke="#4596AB" stroke-dasharray="83.7 167.5 " fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
 
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" fill="#000" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">30%</text>
</svg>
```

**Пример - 75% заполнения**

`stroke-dasharray="188.4 62.8 "` Сумма длин черты и пробела должна быть равна всей длине окружности `251.2`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<!--Серая окружность -->
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="transparent" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="1" />

<!-- Цветной сегмент -->
<path id="progress" stroke-width="3" stroke="#4596AB" stroke-dasharray="188.4  62.8 " fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
 
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" fill="#000" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">75%</text>
</svg>
```

### Пример анимации

Здесь анимация роста цветной полоски достигается изменением параметров `stroke-dasharray`

```
progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

Длина черты увеличивается от `0` до полной длины окружности `251.2` соответственно пробел уменьшается от полной длины `251.2` до `0`

```js
var count = $(('#count'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
body{text-align:center;font-family:sans-serif;background:#080808;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="animated" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
 <!-- Цветной сегмент -->
 <path id="progress" stroke-width="3" stroke="#4596AB" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  <!-- Белый круг, вокруг которого идёт заполнение цветного сегмента -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="38" fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
   <!-- Вывод процентов внутри круга -->
  <text id="count" x="50" y="50" fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" dy="7" font-size="20">100%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо!буду пробовать!

Comment: @verstak44444 Да не за что. Если пример вам был полезен, не забудьте поставить галочку (рядом с треугольниками)

Comment: @verstak44444 всё таки забыли :) Случайно вышел на этот старый пост из поисковика